# Hide buy button in product page in same products

Tags: magento

I have one issue. It's able to make in magento that in some products don't show add to cart button. Because I want make these products just informational and not buyable.

Is any hack in magento like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom attribute to your products that would mark them as not available for sale. After doing this, you can just modify your templates to not show the buy/add to cart buttons if the attribute is set to true.

Of course, good practice would suggest that you also prevent these products from actually being added to the cart manually, just hook an observer to the card add event and check for the attribute and skip if it's set to true.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I'm little bit newbie coder, so what I need to write in product template? What code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to customize code
just set product stock `0` then enable `Display Out of Stock Products`

- set product stock 0
- Enable `Display Out of Stock Products`
- Set `Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` to 1

that's it.

When customer want to add product to cart, the system will not accept is because of the stock level.

PS : I suggest this technique is because of your request which you specified "but buyable" in your question.

Comment: Ahhh, my broken english language, I made mistake - informational, and not buyable :) So this method will not work...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extension [Click here for extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/call-for-price-9.html) which I guess is suitable for your question:

[Call For Price](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/call-for-price-9.html)